# Function with known domain

Tags: functions

Find a function(not piecewise) that has a domain A={1}∪(2,3). There are no limitations to it as long as it is not a multivariable function.  Thanks in advance

Comment: How is the set $(2,3)$ defined here? And what is a multivariable function? Btw, it is explicitly stated that the tag "domain-theory" should not be used by questions about a domain of a function. I would just say: $f$ is a function $A\to\mathbb R$ prescribed by $a\mapsto0$ for each $a\in A$. Am I missing something?

Comment: The "piecewise" thing is not well-defined. That being said, try something like $\sqrt{-(x-1)^2(x-2)(x-3)}$

Comment: Um, any real function restricted to A?  $f(x) = x^2$.  What exactly does piecewise mean in this context?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the function $f(x)=x$ defined over $\{1\}\cup(2,3)$ satisfies the requirement.

But probably the question is to find an expression whose “domain of definedness” is the given set.

Square roots are good for limiting the domain to an interval: the polynomial $(x-2)(3-x)$ is positive only over $(2,3)$, so one might think to
$$
\sqrt{\frac{1}{(x-2)(3-x)}}
$$
Can you sneak in something that will make the expression also defined at $1$?